# Selenium IDE: Find specific text and press button

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a list of li's within an ul, where the li would look like:

```
<li class="list-group-item operator">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a href="/index.php?page=excursion_transport&amp;sub_page=operators&amp;mode=edit&amp;id=10" class="tooltip-hook" title="" data-original-title="Rediger operatøren">
                    <span class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></span>
                </a>
                <span class="text-muted tooltip-hook" title="" data-original-title="Operatøren kan ikke slettes da den har transportmidler.">
                    <span class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <a href="/index.php?page=excursion_transport&amp;sub_page=operators&amp;mode=edit&amp;id=10">Ice Cap Tours</a>
        </li>
```

How do I with Selenium IDE find the text "Ice Cap Tours" and at the same time press the pencil that are present in the "span class='fa-pencil'"?

Comment: Show code you've tried already

Comment: I have tried "VerifyText" and then a "Click", but that dit not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to interact with them you'd need the following locators

```
//a[contains(text(),'Ice Cap Tours')]//..

//span[contains(@class, 'fa-pencil')]
```

The first will just look for the span containing the text you're after, and the "//.." navigates up to the parent element (the a tag) to click on the link

The second one will look for the span whos class contains "fa-pencil", you may have had trouble with the other suggested locators as they will have been looking for an exact match of the class, rather than just a class which contains that one

Comment: Thanks for your answer. These two lines, should they be written as one long line in "Target"?

Comment: Like: //a[contains(text(),'Ice Cap Tours')]//..//span[contains(@class, 'fa-pencil')]

Answer (score 0):

Use `click` or `clickAndWait` Command and in Target you can write xpath as `//a[text()='Ice Cap Tours']//preceding-sibling::div/a[@class='fa-pencil']`

Comment: Hi Peter, 

I have edited my post with the original code, how do I then do it?

I thought that an example would be easier that the real code, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Hi again @peter, it failed...I received the following in the log: [error] Element //a[text()='Ice Cap Tours']//preceding-sibling::div/a[@class='fa-pencil'] not found

Comment: First try to locate element using `//a[text()='Ice Cap Tours']//preceding-sibling::div` .

Comment: I just tried: //a[contains(text(),'Ice Cap Tours')] and that worked for the first part of it, the second part still fails.

Comment: `//a[contains(text(),'Ice Cap Tours')]//preceding-sibling::div/a` try to locate elements by adding one by one tag. And make sure that it is the only element present on the page, else it will locate other element and in that case the xpath will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try bellow xpath :

```
//a[normalize-space()='Ice Cap Tours']/preceding-sibling::div/a/span[contains(@class,'fa-pencil')]
```

Here is explanation :

```
//a[normalize-space()='Ice Cap Tours']
```

This will locate your anchor tag which having text `Ice Cap Tours`

```
/preceding-sibling::div
```

Used to navigate to locate the preceding sibling node of `a` tag. In your case `div` is preceding sibling of `a` tag

```
div/a/span[contains(@class,'fa-pencil')]
```

Will locate your `span` which having class name `pencil`